# Hc sticky plugin IE11 issue - Navigation bar not going full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, hcsticky

I've been using for a while now the HC-sticky plugin for sticky elements. It's always working fantastically in every browser but IE11. It seems like the width of the element is not properly calculated, ending up with the menu bar not going full width. Anyone has experimented something similar? Is there a workaround for it?

[image]

Comment: How is your page designed? Could you please add an example or a screenshot to show your page so that it will be esaier to reprodcue your issue and help with you?

Comment: I have updated a screenshot of the issue, as you will see the width of the header it's calculated by the sticky plugin and inserted inline. The calculation is missing around 70 px and the navbar is not going full-width